# show components in nested route in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

this is my code why it doesnt show sale componet? i want in the sale component access to both title & id of each book. but after click on link to go to sale nothing happens .how can i handle this  issue? thank you for your help!

App.js

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<Layout component={Dashboard} />} />
<Routes>
  <Route path="books">
    {/* books */}
    <Route index element={<Layout component={Dashboard} />} />
    {/* /books/:title/:id" */}
    <Route path=":title/:id">
      <Route index element={<Layout component={BookDetail} />} />
      {/* /books/:title/:id" */}
      <Route path="sale" element={<Layout component={SaleStore} />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

Dashboard

```
{books.map((book) => (
  <div className="col" key={book.id}>
    <div className="card h-100" >
      <div className="card-img-top pb-5 mb-5">
    </div>
    <div className="card-body">
      <Link to={`${book.title}/${book.id}`}> // "/books/:title/:id"
        <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
          {book.title}
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

detail

```
const { title, id } = useParams();
console.log("book Title:", title);
console.log("book Id:", id);

...

<Link to="sale"> // "/books/:title/:id/sale"
  <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
    go to sale
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: FWIW, the code from *this* post copied into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/show-components-in-nested-route-in-react-2gz28z) runs as expected, e.g. the UI can route/navigate to the sale page. What are the exact reproduction steps you are taking to not be able to navigate to the `"/books/:title/:id/sale"` route?

Answer (score -1):

In your App.js, the path for the sale component is set as /books/sale, but in your BookDetail component, the link to the sale component is specified as to="sale", which would result in a relative path of /books/:title/:id/sale.

```html
// App.js

<Route path="books">
  <Route path=":title/:id">
    <Route index element={<Layout component={BookDetail} />} />
    <Route path="sale" element={<Layout component={SaleStore} />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

```html
// BookDetail.js

<Link to={`sale`}>
  <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
    go to sale
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Look more closely at the OP's code and notice that the `SaleStore` component ***is*** rendered on path `"/books/:title/:id/sale"`. You basically copy/pasted their code, and removed the comments and index route rendering the `Dashboard`. This doesn't really answer the question or address the issue the OP says they have.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like below

```
// Inside BookDetail component
    <Link to={`./sale`}>
      <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
        Go to Sale
      </button>
    </Link>
```